# CLBeaconRegion initWithProximityUUID returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

While trying to instantiate CLBeaconRegion, I always get nil value.

I have the following code:

```
NSUUID *myUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"11111111111111111111111111111111"];
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:myUUID
                                                                identifier:@"myCompany"];

CLLocationManager *locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locManager setDelegate:self];
[locManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
```

This fails with at last line beacause of: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: region != nil', which is clear, since region is nil.

But why is region nil? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your uuid seems to have an invalid format, so it is nil and therefore also the region

a valid uuid is e.g. `93606DCE-56C1-4FE1-9517-AA0B6EADB0B2`

use `uuidgen` tool to create uuids

Comment: Yea, thanks. That's what I also concluded just now. Should have looked for more. Thanks!

Comment: I will no worries, but you can't accept it so soon.